# How to check whether records are paginated / will paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I'm using the [WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) Ruby gem `v3.1.6`.

Given you may run `@posts = Post.all.paginate(page: params[:page])` or `@posts = Post.all`, is there a method to check if `@posts` are being currently paginated? That is, are `@posts` running/using WillPaginate?

I'm looking to make something as follows:

```
if @posts.will_paginate? # or @posts.paginated?
  # paginated @posts
else
  # not paginated @posts
```

---

By looking at the gem [source code](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L73) I'd use...

```
def will_paginate? # or paginated?
  @posts.respond_to?(:total_pages)
end
```

... or check someway `WillPaginate` is a class ancestor of `@posts`, but probably there is a better way to check whether records are paginated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def paginated?
  @posts.count > WillPaginate.per_page
end
```

You can set the `per_page` on the Post model, locally, or globally via `WillPaginate.per_page`.

**Edit after discussion**

model/car.rb

```
class Car
  def paginated? 
    false
  end
end
```

model/post.rb

```
class Post
  def paginated? 
    true
  end
end
```

**OR**

views/shared/_universal.html.erb

```
<!-- renders your universal layout for the number of objects -->
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <div><%= item.property %></div>
<% end %>
```

views/cars/index.html.erb

```
...
<%= render partial 'shared/_universal.html.erb', locals: { items: @cars } %>
```

views/posts/index.html.erb

```
...
<%= render partial 'shared/_universal.html.erb', locals: { items: @posts } %>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Comment: With "are records paginated?" I mean "are records running/using WillPaginate?". Question updated for clarity.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this because Models aren't defined under some `WillPaginate`. It's more like `WillPaginate` hooks beneath the model. So, you can't know ahead of calling the method whether or not you will be using it. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Maybe I can solve the root issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm implementing a "universal template" for indexing records, which template handles both the case records are paginated and the case those are not. In the former case the pagination will be shown while in the latter it will be not.

Comment: So, for example, the Post model might be paginated, but the Car model might not?

Comment: Yes, and both Post and Car might use/render the same (partial) template.

Comment: Okay, well, if you really want to do it this way, you should just place a simple helper in each model. I'll update my answer to include that. But it sounds a lot more like you should be splitting up your "universal template" into a partial that ignores pagination. Then each model's subsequent view has pagination below. I'll add all of this to my answer.

Comment: After your edit – I think it could be improved: without stating the `paginated?` method in each model but in a shared, included module (or perhaps extending `WillPaginate` in a Rails initializer or, better, at the core BTW See [this](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/592)), and checking pagination in `views/shared/_universal.html.erb` where `will_paginate @records` runs depending on `paginated?`.